# FBSDKProfilePictureView showing up blank

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-ios-sdk, app-transport-security

I'm trying to display a user's profile picture from Facebook using FBSDKProfilePictureView, however it is just showing up as blank when I set the profile ID. I get the Profile ID using the Graph API and the /me node. I then set the ID in my setupCell method which is called in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, the setup is straight forward, just the following:

```
public func setupCell(userId: String?) {
    if userId != nil {
        profilePicture.profileID = "4";
    }
    welcomeLabel.text = "Welcome back, Mark"
}
```

(Test data uses Zuckerberg's info)

I've verified the userId is set, so it is getting the user id. I then override layoutSubviews like so:

```
override public func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = profilePicture.bounds.height / 2.0
    profilePicture.clipsToBounds = true
    profilePicture.setNeedsImageUpdate()

    welcomeLabel.sizeToFit()
}
```

I thought setting the needsImageUpdate() would do it, but apparently not. I found another post on here advising me to add two more domains to my app transport security, here's the relevant parts of that that I have:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>1.1</string>
        </dict>
        <key>akamai.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>1.1</string>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>1.1</string>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here? It has to be something somewhat easy. Any other data that may needed I can provide, I'd love any help you can provide!

Comment: you pass id....facebook provide link for every user  profile

Comment: I set the ID in the setupCell method, I'm just using test data in case the ID I'm getting back isn't valid

Comment: you got a link from facebook or not?

Comment: I've got a user ID from the profile of the user logged in. I use Facebook sdk's graph API to get it